# Heroku & NodeJS Reading User Stream fails when supplying since parameter

Tags: facebook, node.js, facebook-graph-api, heroku

I have followed the Facebook's Heroku app tutorial with NodeJS, I am pretty sure that I have set up the application and can make changes. However, I have a problem, in the web.js, I have modified a socket message to this:

```
  session.graphCall('/me/feed')(function(result) {
     socket_manager.send(socket_id, 'feed', result);
  });
```

It returns the expected data. (Tested in Graph API Explorer)
However, when I make the graph call with `/me/feed?since=2011` it says: `{"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException"}` I cannot really know what I am doing wrong, it is taking the required `read_stream` permission and working fine without since parameter.

What can be the problem? I thought the node facebook client was passing the token (as it can read without parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using this API? https://github.com/DracoBlue/node-facebook-client

If so it looks like the graphCall takes a second param which is for additionalParams.  Can you try:

```
session.graphCall('/me/feed', {since: 2011})(function(result) {
 socket_manager.send(socket_id, 'feed', result);
});
```

Comment: It perfectly works! Thanks! 
BTW, even If I wrote ?since=2011 on the question here, I found out that it was /?since=2011 in my code, that was acuasing problem, too. Notice for future users.